# How to back up game data in galaxy y s5360

Tags: samsung, 2.3-gingerbread, backup, google-play-services, samsung-galaxy-y

I have Samsung galaxy y s5360 in which i installed hill-climb racing  i want to backup game data but i dont have google play service and cannot installed it because of low space is there any way to back up without google play service and transfer it to another phone

Comment: try Backup Android App and Data With **Ultimate Backup Tool**

Comment: The Ultimate Backup Tool requires Android 4.0 or higher and can't be used in this case as the device is on Android 2.3.